# MySQL select calculate 2 fields based on other field

Tags: mysql, sum

Let's say i have a table like this

```
| user | symbol | status | value |
----------------------------------
| 101  | A      | 1      | 20    |
| 102  | A      | 1      | 20    |
| 103  | A      | 1      | 20    |
| 101  | A      | 0      | 20    |
| 102  | B      | 1      | 20    |
| 103  | A      | 1      | 20    |
| 101  | A      | 0      | 20    |
| 102  | A      | 1      | 20    |
| 103  | A      | 0      | 20    |
| 101  | B      | 1      | 20    |
| 102  | A      | 0      | 20    |
```

and i want the result like this (all value change to minus that have status = 0)

```
| user | symbol | differences |
----------------------------------
| 101  | A      | -20         |
| 101  | B      | 20          |
| 102  | A      | 20          |
| 102  | B      | 20          |
| 103  | A      | 20          |
```

Please help, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want update/select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression for changing the value to minus if `status` = 0.

**Query**

```
 select `user`, `symbol`, 
 sum(case when `status` = 0 then `value` * -1 else `value` end) as differences
 from `your_table_name`
 group by `user`, `symbol`
 order by `user`, `symbol`;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0adc4/1)

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution using `CASE..WHEN` below:

```
SELECT user,
       symbol,
   CASE WHEN status > 0 THEN value
        ELSE -value END as differences
 FROM yourTable;
```

Though in this particular case, you can also use math:

```
SELECT user, 
       symbol,
       (value * (2*status-1)) as differences
  FROM yourTable;
```

If you also want to aggregate the results, then you can change the queries above to use a `GROUP BY` with `SUM` as the aggregation:

```
SELECT  user,
       symbol,
   SUM(CASE WHEN status > 0 THEN value
        ELSE -value END) as differences
 FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user, symbol;
```

And the equivalent aggregated query, using the arithmetic:

```
SELECT user, 
       symbol,
       SUM(value * (2*status-1)) as differences
  FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY user, symbol;
```

Comment: Status value is zero and one, would `value * -status` would convert it to zero,instead of turning it into negative.

Comment: Correct math workaround would be `(2*status-1) * value`